# Bokeh plotting only specific column from web scraped data

Tags: python, bokeh

The code below extracts data from two different websites and Bokeh  plots the data. Issue is when I plot "Volumes" data against datatime.now() on x axis it gets plotted but when I plot "Open" or "Lasts" data my Bokeh plot is blank. I thought that the scraped data contains a garbage character but if so then Volumes should also not get plotted. This issue is occurring with "ugaz" and "dgaz" as well where output is exported to tags1.text and tags2.text. Its been a while I am trying to understand.

However, when I print(source.data) output is coming as

> {'x': [datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 5, 21, 15, 38, 712611)], 'y': ['1094'], 'y1': ['2.095']}

The code is:

```
 import requests
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 from bokeh.models import Range1d, LinearAxis
 import time
 from datetime import datetime
 from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, DatetimeTickFormatter
 from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
 from math import radians
 import pandas as pd

 p = figure()

 Volumes = []
 Opens = []
 Lasts=[]
 Contracts =[]
 Lows = []
 Highs = []

 res3  = requests.get('https://shared.websol.barchart.com/quotes/quote.php? 
 page=quote&sym=ng&x=13&y=8&domain=if&display_ice=1&enabled_ice_exchanges=&tz=0&ed=0')
 res1  = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ugaz?ltr=1')
 res2  = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/dgaz?ltr=1')
 soup1 = BeautifulSoup(res1.text,'html.parser')
 soup2 = BeautifulSoup(res2.text,'html.parser')
 tags1 = soup1.find_all('span')[11]
 tags2 = soup2.find_all('span')[11]
 soup3 = BeautifulSoup(res3.text, 'lxml')
 soup3.prettify()
 data_rows = soup3.findAll('tr')[2:]
 i = range(len(data_rows))
 for td in data_rows:
 Volume = td.findAll('td')[6].text
 Volumes.append(Volume)
 Open = td.findAll('td')[3].text
 Opens.append(Open)
 Last = td.findAll('td')[1].text
 Lasts.append(Last)
 Contract = td.findAll('td')[0].text
 Contracts.append(Contract)
 Low = td.findAll('td')[5].text
 Lows.append(Low)
 High = td.findAll('td')[4].text
 Highs.append(High)

 source = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=[datetime.now()],y=[Volumes[2]], y1=[Opens[2]]))

 p.circle(x ='x', y ='y',source=source,color='blue')
 p.circle(x ='x', y ='y1',source=source,color='red')  

 show(p)
```

Comment: Are actually converting the scraped strings to numerical values somewhere? It does not appear so in the code above. Regardless, whatever issue there is, is in your data. It's not going to be possible to help without knowing what it is. You should examine exactly what values are being put in the CDS (e.g., by printing them).

Comment: @bigreddot the CDS is printing values. See output above

Comment: It was scrolled off the page with the long code. I have edited to make it more visibly obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not converting all the values to numbers:

```
{
    'x':  [datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 5, 21, 15, 38, 712611)], 
    'y':  ['1094'],  # value in list is a string -- BAD
    'y1': ['2.095']  # value in list is a string -- BAD
}
```

Unless you are specifically plotting *categorical* values (not the case here), then values in CDS columns should generally always be numbers.

You can convert strings to numbers by calling the built-in `float` function on them.

Comment: what’s confusing to me is I am not converting Y( Volumes) to number and they are getting plotted but Y1 ( Opens, Lasts) is not. Any help in code would be appreciated.

Comment: Convert them all to numbers. That is the correct thing to do, regardless.